# Filter Array attribute from objects array based on another array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to filter an array of objects with an array attribute based on another array:

```
[
  {
   id: 50,
   name: 'test1',
   countries: ['RO','GB'],
  }, {
    id: 51,
    name: 'test2',
    countries: ['DE', 'RO'],
  }, {
    id: 52,
    name: 'test3',
    countries: ['DE'],
  }
]
```

I want to return an array of objects that can by filtered by an array of countries, meaning if I want to filter by 1, 2 countries.

```
1. countries: ['RO']
```

or

```
2. countries: ['RO', 'DE'],
```

The expected output would be:

1.

```
[
  {
   id: 50,
   name: 'test1',
   countries: ['RO', 'DE' ,'GB'],
  }, {
    id: 51,
    name: 'test2',
    countries: ['DE', 'RO'],
  }
]
```

2.

```
[
  {
   id: 50,
   name: 'test1',
   countries: ['RO', 'DE' ,'GB'],
  }, {
    id: 51,
    name: 'test2',
    countries: ['DE', 'RO'],
  }, {
    id: 52,
    name: 'test3',
    countries: ['DE'],
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter()` and `includes()` methods;

```js
var import1 = [
  {
   id: 50,
   name: 'test1',
   countries: ['RO','GB'],
  }, {
    id: 51,
    name: 'test2',
    countries: ['DE', 'RO'],
  }, {
    id: 52,
    name: 'test3',
    countries: ['DE'],
  }
];

var export1 =  import1.filter(function(importz){
 
return importz.countries.includes("DE");
});

console.log(export1);
```

Comment: the includes should expect an array of strings, found out how to filter them:   array1.filter(object => object.countries.find(country => arrayOfCountries.includes(country)))

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to find multiple values exist in javascript array

```
var containsAll = arr1.every(function (i) { return arr2.includes(i); });
```